# When PUTting with an id in the URL and in the body, which one wins?

Tags: rest, http, get, put

Trying to figure out the correct restful behaviour in the following case:

- there is an endpoint /objects/{id} with the methods GET and PUT
- the objects can be an arbitrary json and for some reason they have their own id as a key, e.g. `{"id": 1}`
- on `GET /objects/1` I should obviously revceive `{"id": 1}`
- What happens when I `PUT /objects/1 {"id": 2}`?

These are the options which for me have appeal in descending order:

- Not-OK Status on PUTting - signal a conflict and don't allow the PUT
- Don't include the `id` in the object in the first place. *Problem:* My Objects can be really complicated and have the id woven into their nested structure, making it hard to filter out/factor in again
- URL id wins (ignore body id). *Problem:* When GETing again, I don't get what I PUTted but something else
- body wins. *Problem:* What I putted ends up somewhere else completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.

The identifier of a resource and its representation are not required to agree in any semantically significant way, in much the same way that the fully qualified path of a file is not required to agree with its contents, in much the same way that a value in a dictionary is not required to agree with its key.

```
GET /objects/1

200 OK

{ "id": 2 }
```

As far as HTTP is concerned, that's perfectly valid, just as it would be for

```
GET /fbb477c8-e2f3-4581-9c44-27305de6ebee

200 OK

{ "id": 2 }
```

The key piece of the standard that you need to lean on is this:

> An origin server SHOULD verify that the PUT representation is consistent with any constraints the server has for the target resource that cannot or will not be changed by the PUT.

It's perfectly within the rules to say that any representation `PUT` to `/fbb477c8-e2f3-4581-9c44-27305de6ebee` has to be about `id:1`, and to reject as inconsistent requests that would not satisfy that invariant.  [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) is the usual status code to use in this case.

And of course that is equally true of the identifier `/objects/1`.